# using variable as method in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what i am trying to achieve is relatively simple. I have different scopes for each page type in a page model. So in my controller I do this,

```
  def employer
    @body_class = "employer membership"
    is_page_present?(:employer_pages) #this checks to see if a page has user generated content for the controller action
  end 

private 

  def set_panel_sections(page)
    @page_data = CorporatePage.page.last
    @section_one = @page_data.corporate_panels.section_one
    @section_two = @page_data.corporate_panels.section_two
  end

  def is_page_present?(page_type)
    if CorporatePage.("#{page_type}").any?
      raise
      set_panel_sections(page_type)
    else
      @section_one = nil
    end
  end
```

I have tried different variations, including without concatenation, but all to no avail.

I get the error

```
undefined method `call' for #<Class:0x007f833b40b8f0>
```

and without the concatenation i get `undefined method page_type`

But in my rails console I can do this..

```
2.1.2 :001 > CorporatePage.employer_page.any?
   (19.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `corporate_pages`  WHERE `corporate_pages`.`static_descriptor` = 'employer'
 => true 
2.1.2 :002 > CorporatePage.employee_page.any?
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `corporate_pages`  WHERE `corporate_pages`.`static_descriptor` = 'employee'
 => false
```

So, for a more insightful answer I want to know, a method call isnt a string or a symbol, what is it?

How do I fix this current issue?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, the reason you get the error you do is because `obj.()` is shorthand for `obj.call`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here is `send`:

```
  def is_page_present?(page_type)
    if CorporatePage.send(page_type).any?         
      set_panel_sections(page_type)
    else
      @section_one = nil
    end
  end
```

`send` will call the method defined at `page_type` at the class instance.

Comment: Use `public_send` instead of `send` whenever possible to avoid bypassing method visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the send method. You can find a basic explanation of it here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-send.

In you situation, you would change `if CorporatePage.("#{page_type}").any?` to `if CorporatePage.send(page_type).any?` and that should get you what you are after.

Comment: Use `public_send` instead of `send` whenever possible to avoid bypassing method visibility.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I wasn't aware of that until now. I will make sure to utilize that from now on.